# Facebook isValidRedirect always return false

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working on SDK v.4 but something seems wrong with Class FacebookRedirectLoginHelper method isValidRedirect.

the SDK code is

```
 protected function isValidRedirect()
  {
    return $this->getCode() && isset($_GET['state'])
        && $_GET['state'] == $this->state;
  }
```

While `$_GET['state']` is the parameter in the callback URL and `$this->state` is assigned by the function `random()` which generates a cryptographically secure pseudrandom number.

Both $_GET['state'] and $this->state; will never return true!

It should be check $_SESSION not $_GET

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you look closely at the code, the `loadState()` function actually looks for the state in the `$_SESSION` and loads it into `$this->state`. The `isValidRedirect()` is called after, which means it uses the `$_SESSION` loaded `state`.

You can also see that `$_GET['state']` exists in the URL after logging in with Facebook, so this check is valid. If it wasn't, the code would never be exchanged for an `access_token`.

Comment: can you please explain your answer with example? how to avoid above condition to happen? i.e. $_GET['state'] & $this->state doesn't match.

Comment: When facebook returns to my url, its calling again getLoginUrl() function.

So my question is, is it valid to give condition like if($_SESSION[‘FBRLH_state’] == ''), then only call function getLoginUrl() ?

Comment: The `getLoginUrl()` function doesn't make a API call so it shouldn't matter if it's called again in your code. The better thing to do is look for `$_GET['code']` as that's what Facebook will return on login. Have a look at my example here: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/

Comment: hii Niraj
There is no mention of $_GET['code'] in you page.
I get that code, but the session is null and I have no idea how to get the token in exchage of the code. what  to do?

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem, and I just fixed it.

The point is about the 'state' variable.

`getLoginUrl()` will generate a new 'state', so I only call `getLoginUrl()` in the first stage.

Stage 1:
I show a page, with a link generated by `getLoginUrl()`. 
Here I got a state, say the value is X.

Stage 2:
the user clicks on the link, and then is redirected to Facebook Oath dialog, in which the user will type in their Facebook name and password, and allow the app to access the user's public info.

Stage 3:
The user is redirected back to my site, with a 'state', and the value is X.

If I called `getLoginUrl()` here, a new 'state' will be generated, 
hence isValidRedirect() will always return false.

So I check `isset($_GET['state'])` first, 
and don't call `getLoginUrl()` when `isset($_GET['state'])` is `TRUE`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I knew this was the case and coded my application to avoid this issue but I still get it. I've added a var_dump to the storeState function so I can tell when it is updating the session value. It gets run once to generate the url as expected, and when I return from facebook it does not get run a single time and yet the session value and get value never match for some reason. I've spent hours of frustrating time on this and I can't see how this is happening.